# Xcode 15: App is crashing when setting custom Navigation bar for navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, xcode15, ios17

I have made a custom class for UINavigationBar which has all the custom features I need for an application.
After initialising the class I am adding it to the navigation controller like this

```
if (!navBar) {
    navBar=[[NavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame];
    [self.navigationController setValue:navBar forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
 }
```

My app is crashing on the line

```
[self.navigationController setValue:navBar forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

Till Xcode 14 its working fine but on Xcode 15 it's crashing. Any help is highly appreciated.

below is the crash that I am getting

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationBar layoutSubviews], UINavigationBar.m:3856
```

Comment: You're using private API via the key path, it's not safe at all. You could think about another way like a custom `navigationItem` for titleView, leftItem, right item, etc.

Comment: I agree with @son, but please at least add the crash's stack trace to the question—without it it's not possible to figure out the reason of the crash.

Comment: thanks  @lazarevzubov for the suggestion. My bad that I haven't added the crash that I am getting.
I have added now. Also I was using valueForKeyPath:@"navigationbar" and it was working fine till Xcode 14 and its even working on iOS 16 when build with Xcode 15. Its only crashing when I am running with combination of  Xcode 15 and iOS 17

Comment: This custom navigation bar is being used in more than 15 view controllers. So, I didn't want to go in each one of them and create separate buttons and navigations items, that why I created a separate custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue after putting the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
   [self.navigationController setValue:navBar forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
}
```

After this code is working and not crashing anymore